# How to find $a \in R$ such that the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}3x+2&,\;\;x<2\\x^2+a&,\;\;x\geq 2\end{cases}$?

Tags: limits

How to find $a \in R$ such that the function:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}3x+2&,\;\;x<2\\{}\\x^2+a&,\;\;x\geq 2\end{cases}$$
is continuous.

I guess I need to compute left and right limits:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^-}3x+2=8$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^+}x^2+a=a+4$$

Comment: "Such that the function..."  What? Is continuous?

Comment: such that the function.. ?

Comment: Oops, of corse. Sorry! :)

Comment: @qexi, don't use double line space \\{}\\ in the questions' title. It comes up too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. The function is continuous (at $x=2$) if the limits from both sides are equal so
$$8 = a+4 $$
implies...?

Comment: 4... Is it all? :)

Comment: @qexi Yep, that is correct!

Comment: So simple... :) Thanks!

Comment: @qexi You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So you already have it: it must be

$$\lim_{x\to 2^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 2^-}f(x)\iff a+4=8$$